# How to share Firebase Realtime Database access logic between a Firebase Cloud Function and a web client?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to share Firebase Realtime Database access logic between a Firebase Cloud Function that uses the Firebase Admin SDK and a JavaScript web client that uses the Firebase Realtime Database SDK. Both SDKs provide a `Database` interface with the same methods but different TypeScript types. How to pas an instance of either firebase.database.Database or admin.database.Database to a shared function in order to reuse data access logic?

shared.ts (doesn't work)

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

export async function getGreeting(database: firebase.database.Database | admin.database.Database): Promise<string> {
  const greetingRef = database.ref('/greeting')
  return await greetingRef.once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
}
```

shared.ts (works, but I lose typing support in my editor)

```
export async function getGreeting(database: any): Promise<string> {
  const greetingRef = database.ref('/greeting')
  return await greetingRef.once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
}
```

admin-cloud-function.ts

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as shared from './shared'

async function greet() {
    let greeting = await shared.getGreeting(admin.database())
    console.log(greeting)
}
```

web-client.ts

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import * as shared from './shared'

async function greet() {
    let greeting = await shared.getGreeting(firebase.database())
    console.log(greeting)
}
```

Is this a good approach or should I structure my code differently?

Comment: This isn't a good solution, but FWIW you could probably have `getGreeting()` accept database as `any` but then within the function cast it to a stronger type, e.g. `const db = database as firebase.database;` so that you get typing support back.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer What would be a better solution? Would it be better to duplicate the data access code for both `firebase` and `firebase-admin` database instances?

Comment: @Korneal Oh! I'm sorry. I meant to convey that /my/ solution isn't a good one but would work as a wokraround. What you are trying to do is totally reasonable but unfortunately not well supported by our SDKs at the moment. We're having some internal discussions about how we might enable this in the future though.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer Thank you for clarifying. Would my approach be better supported with the new Cloud Firestore?

Comment: Unfortunately it's actually less supported because for Cloud Firestore the Firebase SDK for the web has a different API than the gcloud SDK for use in server environments (which includes Cloud Functions). So the typings will necessarily be different.  So you'd need to duplicate your code (at least to some degree) for the two environments. I've pinged some folks internally about this. Perhaps we can come up with some best practices for this sort of thing in the future.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer is code duplication still necessary in 2019? If so, are there any open issues we could follow to stay up to date in case this is improved in the future?